# Side by side hats

Tags: accents

I am trying to typeset a symbol with two hats, side by side. Like this, but less ugly (regular hat for comparison):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hat{X}  \overset{\wedge \wedge}{X}$
\end{document}
```

How can I do this so that it looks good next to a symbol with a regular hat? Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here I provide `\dhat{}` and take the effort to account for the slant by adding an `\hspace` equal to `0.2\ht0` where the argument has been stuffed in the 0 box (I am assuming a slant value [tan(slantangle)] of 0.2).  EDITED to work in the smaller mathstyles.  REEDITED to refine inter-hat kern for more uniformity across mathstyles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{0pt}\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\dhat#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackon{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\hspace{.2\ht0}%
  \hat{\vphantom{#1}}\kern\dimexpr2.2\LMpt+.7pt\relax\hat{\vphantom{#1}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$\hat{X}   \dhat{X} \dhat{x}$

$\scriptstyle \hat{X}   \dhat{X} \dhat{x}$

$\scriptscriptstyle \hat{X}   \dhat{X} \dhat{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

While the above code is most descriptive at showing how the `stackengine` parameters must be defined, the following replacement definition:

```
\def\dhat#1{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\hspace{.2\ht0}%
  \hat{\vphantom{#1}}\kern\dimexpr2.2\LMpt+.7pt\relax\hat{\vphantom{#1}}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}%
}
```

will allow the line `\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{0pt}\def\useanchorwidth{T}` to be eliminated, thus preventing global redefinition of those package settings.